# Submitting a form with large files

Tags: php, ajax, forms, laravel

I am developing a web app with laravel and submitting a form with multiple files using ajax.

I have noticed that when I select large files I get a Post error. In the controller I printed out the data that has been received and I get an empty array. On the other hand if I select small files the data is being received and the files are being saved and when I print out I get the array with all the files and other data.

Why is the data not being received?

Comment: Show source code..

Comment: Check the `post_max_size` and max `upload_max_filesize` in your php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the PHP configuration. Check your `php.ini`, there are the parameters `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`.

To allow for 10 megabytes upload size, use

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M
```

You may also need to increase other timeouts if the upload is slow.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your php.ini file:

Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
http://php.net/post-max-size

```
post_max_size = 128M
```

Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.

http://php.net/upload-max-filesize

```
upload_max_filesize = 128M
```

Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request

```
max_file_uploads = 20
```

Adjust the values to your needs.